# C++ using getline() to append 2 lines of an input file into an array

Tags: c++

this is my first time coming to stackoverflow I have been really struggling with this simple problem..

Here's an example of my input file...

---

```
Korn
2
Nu Metal
Alternative Metal
1993
2021
29
"Blind" 1995
```

---

Here is a snippet of my code...

---

```
//Read Artists Name From File into the Array
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{

    //Read Artist's Name From File into the Array
    getline(inputFile, artistArray[index].artistsName);

    //Read Number of Genre's per Artist
    inputFile >> artistArray[index].numOfGenres; 

    for (int count = 0; count < artistArray[index].numOfGenres; count++)
    {
        //Read Genre From File into the Array
        inputFile >> artistArray[repeatGenre].genre;
        repeatGenre++;
    }

    //Read Artist's Starting Year From File into the Array
    inputFile >> artistArray[index].startingYear;

    //Read Artist's Ending Year From File into the Array
    inputFile >> artistArray[index].endingYear;

    //Read Artist's Number of Tracks from File into the Array
    inputFile >> artistArray[index].numOfTracks;

    for (int count = 0; count < artistArray[index].numOfGenres; count++)
    {
        //Read Track Title 
        inputFile >> artistArray[repeatTracks].trackTitle;

        //Read Track Year
        inputFile >> artistArray[repeatTracks].trackYear;

        //Continue to Next Track
        repeatTracks++; 
    }
}
```

---

& Here are my results.....

---

```
Korn
2
Nu
Metal
Alternative
Metal
1993
2021 29
"Blind" 1995
```

---

HELP for the life of me I cannot figure out how to append "Nu" & "Metal" OR "Alternative" & "Metal" together like the input file has it, it's such a small issue but it is extremely detrimental to my program.

Comment: You want to insert the artist once for each genre and each song? I'd expect the artist class to look something like this instead: `class Artist{ std::vector<Genre> m_genres; std::vector<Song> m_songs; ... };`

Comment: You may be running into this issue: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: I am not allowed to use a vector sadly,,,

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this is basically the result you want for that example:

```cpp
artistArray[index].artistsName = "Korn";
artistArray[index].numOfGenres = 2;
artistArray[repeatGenre].genre = "Nu Metal";
artistArray[repeatGenre + 1].genre = "Alternative Metal";
...
```

The problem would be in your second for loop then. Instead of using the `>>` operator, you should use the `getline()` function. The `>>` operator will not read the whole line. For `std::string`s, the `>>` operator reads in a string until it reaches whitespace.

I would rewrite the loop to be:

```cpp
for (int count = 0; count < artistArray[index].numGenres; count++) {
  std::string genre;
  std::getline(inputFile, genre);
  artistArray[repeatGenre].genre = genre;
  repeatGenre++;
}
```

Edit:
Now that I think about it, this could probably be simplified.

```cpp
for (int count = 0; count < artistArray[index].numGenres; count++) {
  std::getline(inputFile, artistArray[repeatGenre++].genre);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you switch to using `>>` to a string here

```
for (int count = 0; count < artistArray[index].numOfGenres; count++)
{
    //Read Genre From File into the Array
    inputFile >> artistArray[repeatGenre].genre; <<<====
    repeatGenre++;
}
```

`>> std::string` reads a word not a whole line

you need

```
for (int count = 0; count < artistArray[index].numOfGenres; count++)
{
    //Read Genre From File into the Array
    getline(inputFile, artistArray[repeatGenre].genre);
    repeatGenre++;
}
```

I am assuming that .genre is a std::string

Comment: Ah I was NOT thinking...I have been able to append the "Nu" & "Metal" but now the "Alternative" & "Metal" still refuse to link up....

Comment: @smirand - please post updated *complete* program so we can test it. On the face of it your comment makes no sense since both genre strings are read the same way via getline

Comment: Also, when calling `getline()` after use of `>>` you have to account for the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by `>>`. Otherwise, `getline()` sees the `'\n'` left in `stdin` and reads nothing. E.g. `#include <limits>` and before the `getline()` that follows a `>>` call `inputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, when you mix `>>` and `getline()` you must understand that `>>` stops reading at the first whitespace without extracting the whitespace. (`'\n'` is whitespace too). So after reading with `>>` the line ending `'\n'` is left in the input stream unread.

`getline()` reads (by default) until is reaches the `'\n'` character and then extracts the `'\n'` from the input stream but does not store it along with the line read. So if you read with `>>` and then call `getline()`, `getline()` will see the `'\n'` left in the input stream (usually as the 1st character to be read), so `getline()` will read nothing, extracting the `'\n'` and stopping at that point (without any error generated)

To handle switching between `>>` and `getline()`, the iostream library provides the `.ignore()` member function that will extract and discard up to a delimiter (or a fixed number of characters if a count is given). In your case, after reading with `>>` and before reading again with `getline()` you would use:

```cpp
    inputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Which extracts and discards all characters in the input stream up until the first `'\n'` encountered. The use of `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` allows it to ignore up to the maximum number of characters in an input stream.

---

**Reading Your Input File**

Given the lack of a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question, it is impossible to tell what all your issues may be, but if you are using *plain-old-arrays*, that imposes all memory management and bounds checking on you. Instead, a better choice would be to use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) letting the compiler handle the details.

A quick `class` implementation makes things quite easy. For example you could set up your `artist` class, and then simply create a vector-of-artists to hold your collection. For example you could do:

```cpp
class artist
{
  struct track {
    std::string title;
    uint16_t year;
  };
  std::string name;
  std::vector<std::string> genre;
  std::vector<track> tracks;
  uint16_t ngenre, yearstart, yearend, ntracks;
  
 public:
  friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, artist& a);
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const artist& a);
};
```

The `artist` class now holds all data related to one artist, including an additional vector of genre and a vector of struct that holds the title-year information for each title. The `friend` operator overloads for `>>` and `<<` provide a convenient way to encapsulate your input of private class data and a convenient way to output all information per-artist.

(Note: your input data specifies `29` tracks for that artist, but only provides 1-track worth of data. To make the number of tracks consistent with the information provided, that will need to be changed to `1` in the sample data you provided)

To write your `>>` overload to handle the input of all data for one artist, you can do something similar to:

```cpp
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, artist& a)
{
  if (!getline (is, a.name)) {    /* read / validate name */
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> a.ngenre)) {        /* read / validate no. genre */
    return is;
  }
  /* extract characters to '\n' remaining in stdin */
  is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.ngenre; n++) { /* loop a.ngenre times */
    std::string line{};
    if (!getline (is, line)) {    /* read genre into line */
      return is;
    }
    a.genre.push_back (line);     /* add genre to vector */
  }
  
  if (!(is >> a.yearstart)) {     /* read start year */
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> a.yearend)) {       /* read end year */
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> a.ntracks)) {       /* read no. of tracks */
    return is;
  }
  /* extract characters to '\n' remaining in stdin */
  is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.ntracks; n++) {  /* loop a.ntracks times */
    artist::track tmp{};            /* temporary track */
    std::string line{};             /* string for track line */
    if (!getline (is, line)) {      /* read / validate entire track line */
      return is;
    }
    size_t titleend = line.rfind('"');          /* find last " in line */
    if (titleend == std::string::npos) {        /* validate found */
      return is;
    }
    tmp.title = line.substr(1, titleend - 1);   /* extract between " in line */
    /* begin after closing ", find next '1' or '2', extarct title-year */
    tmp.year = std::stoul(line.substr(line.find_first_of("12", titleend + 1)));
    
    a.tracks.push_back (tmp);       /* add track to vector */
  }
  
  return is;
}
```

The comments make clear what is happening. The only challenge comes in separating each title and year. Above presumes that your title is contained in double-quotes where the opening double-quote is the first character in the line, and the final double-quote marks the end of the title.

Essentially what is done above is the closing double-quote is located using [std::basic_string::rfind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) and the index is used to extract between the quotes with [std::basic_string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

For the year [std::stoul](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) is used to convert the string of digits (located by searching after the closing double-quote for the first character in `"12"` as the start of years in the range `1xxx` - `2xxx`). There are many other ways to split the title-line, but using the double-quotes as delimiters will automatically handle names including spaces. (for instance you could read twice using `'"'` as the `getline()` delimiter to read the title)

For your output overload, you can output the data is whatever format you like. One simple way with labels for the different information is:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const artist& a)
{
  /* output Artist label and name, then Genre label */
  os << "\nArtist : " << a.name
     <<  "\nGenre  :";
  
  /* loop outputting genres separated by a comma */
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.genre.size(); n++) {
    if (n) {
      os.put (',');
    }
    os << " " << a.genre[n];
  }
  
  /* output start, end years and number of tracks */
  os << "\nYears  : " << a.yearstart << ", " << a.yearend
     << "\nTracks : " << a.ntracks << '\n';
  
  /* loop outputting all tracks indented by 2-spaces */
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.tracks.size(); n++) {
    os << "  \"" << a.tracks[n].title << "\", " << a.tracks[n].year << '\n';
  }
  
  return os;
}
```

Reading from the sample data provided in the file `dat/artistsinfo.txt` where `29` was replaced with `1` to make the title information consistent, running the code above you would get output from the `<<` overload of:

```
$ ./bin/artistgenre dat/artistsinfo.txt

Artist : Korn
Genre  : Nu Metal, Alternative Metal
Years  : 1993, 2021
Tracks : 1
  "Blind", 1995
```

Adding a `main()` that reads from the filename provided as the first argument to your program, a short complete example could look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

class artist
{
  struct track {
    std::string title;
    uint16_t year;
  };
  std::string name;
  std::vector<std::string> genre;
  std::vector<track> tracks;
  uint16_t ngenre, yearstart, yearend, ntracks;
  
 public:
  friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, artist& a);
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const artist& a);
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2) {  /* validate 1 argument for filename */
    std::cerr << "usage: ./" << argv[0] << " dict_file\n";
    return 1;
  }
  
  artist tmp{};
  std::vector<artist> artists{};
  std::ifstream f (argv[1]);              /* open artists file */
  
  if (!f.is_open()) {   /* validate file open for reading */
    std::cerr << "error: file open failed - " << argv[1] << '\n';
    return 1;
  }
  
  while (f >> tmp) {                /* read all artists from file */
    artists.push_back (tmp);
  }
  
  for (const auto& a : artists) {   /* output all artists to stdout */
    std::cout << a;
  }
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, artist& a)
{
  if (!getline (is, a.name)) {    /* read / validate name */
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> a.ngenre)) {        /* read / validate no. genre */
    return is;
  }
  /* extract characters to '\n' remaining in stdin */
  is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.ngenre; n++) { /* loop a.ngenre times */
    std::string line{};
    if (!getline (is, line)) {    /* read genre into line */
      return is;
    }
    a.genre.push_back (line);     /* add genre to vector */
  }
  
  if (!(is >> a.yearstart)) {     /* read start year */
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> a.yearend)) {       /* read end year */
    return is;
  }
  if (!(is >> a.ntracks)) {       /* read no. of tracks */
    return is;
  }
  /* extract characters to '\n' remaining in stdin */
  is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.ntracks; n++) {  /* loop a.ntracks times */
    artist::track tmp{};            /* temporary track */
    std::string line{};             /* string for track line */
    if (!getline (is, line)) {      /* read / validate entire track line */
      return is;
    }
    size_t titleend = line.rfind('"');          /* find last " in line */
    if (titleend == std::string::npos) {        /* validate found */
      return is;
    }
    tmp.title = line.substr(1, titleend - 1);   /* extract between " in line */
    /* begin after closing ", find next '1' or '2', extarct title-year */
    tmp.year = std::stoul(line.substr(line.find_first_of("12", titleend + 1)));
    
    a.tracks.push_back (tmp);       /* add track to vector */
  }
  
  return is;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const artist& a)
{
  /* output Artist label and name, then Genre label */
  os << "\nArtist : " << a.name
     <<  "\nGenre  :";
  
  /* loop outputting genres separated by a comma */
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.genre.size(); n++) {
    if (n) {
      os.put (',');
    }
    os << " " << a.genre[n];
  }
  
  /* output start, end years and number of tracks */
  os << "\nYears  : " << a.yearstart << ", " << a.yearend
     << "\nTracks : " << a.ntracks << '\n';
  
  /* loop outputting all tracks indented by 2-spaces */
  for (uint16_t n = 0; n < a.tracks.size(); n++) {
    os << "  \"" << a.tracks[n].title << "\", " << a.tracks[n].year << '\n';
  }
  
  return os;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions above. If you would like to edit your question and include a full MRE, I'm happy to check your implementation as well.